# sbt adding dependencies with the same name/organization

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to add a maven-based dependency to my sbt.

Inside its maven I see that it has:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp</groupId>
    <artifactId>illinois-ner</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp</groupId>
    <artifactId>illinois-ner</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <classifier>models-conll</classifier>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp</groupId>
    <artifactId>illinois-ner</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <classifier>models-ontonotes</classifier>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

As you can see these dependencies have the same name, although they are NOT necessarily conflicting (and in fact, ALL of these three are needed). After adding this dependency in the intellij I can see the following libraries loaded:

[image]

On the other hand, if I add these three manually:

```
  "edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp" % "illinois-ner" % "2.8.5-SNAPSHOT" ,
  "edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp" % "illinois-ner" % "2.6" classifier "models-conll",
  "edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp" % "illinois-ner" % "2.6" classifier "models-ontonotes",
```

The externals change to:

[image]

If we force the dependencies,

```
  "edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp" % "illinois-ner" % "2.8.5-SNAPSHOT" force(),
  "edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp" % "illinois-ner" % "2.6" classifier "models-conll" force(),
  "edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp" % "illinois-ner" % "2.6" classifier "models-ontonotes" force(),
```

The external libraries does not change from the 2nd figure.

Any idea how to properly add this dependency?